# How to use React Component to assign value using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to fetch the value from react component **NameField** to pass it inside an object as named value, but its not working and I seemed to be missing something. How I can fetch the value from React component and pass it as value inside a JS expression (which is already inside JSX).

```
return (
.....
    <DataTable items={[{id: 0, Name: <NameField/>}]}</DataTable>
)
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'FiberRootNode'
    |     property 'containerInfo' -> object with constructor 'HTMLDivElement'
    |     property '__reactContainer$2bh06agxh4m' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    --- property 'stateNode' closes the circle
```

Here are the contents of **NameField**

```
function NameField() {
  return (
    <>
      ABC
    </>
  );
}
export default NameField;
```

Comment: `its not working and I seemed to be missing something` what error did you get, or what is happening and what is expected?

Comment: Post updated ...

Comment: How are you using `items` inside `DataTable`?

Comment: DataTable is from a library CoreUI. If I pass  `<DataTable items={[{id: 0, Name: "Abc"}]}</DataTable>` it works, I'm just trying to get value from another React component

Comment: What's inside NameField component?

Comment: `return <>Abc</>`

Comment: when it was working, `Name` was a string (`"Abc"`), now it is a `component` (`NameField`). Hence it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you do a one-liner like that. Try:

```
const Component = ({ props }) => {
  
  // Before return
  const payload = []

  return (
    .....
    {
      payload.push({
        id: 0, 
        name: <NameField/>
      })
    }
    <DataTable items={ payload }/>
  )
}
```

Comment: When I try that inside return before DataTable tag i get `TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.` error.

Comment: Weird. What's in `NameField`?

Comment: `function NameField() { return ( <>Abc</>);}`

Comment: Okay it works now, I was making a mistake ... NameField was returning JSX .. not an object